# Dificuldade em posicionar div no CSS

Tags: css

Estou fazendo um layout com avatar do usuário logado, minha dificuldade está em manter esse círculo verde acompanhar a foto, como segue na imagem abaixo: Utilizando position: absolute; Fica como na foto, porém ao mudar a resolução da tela o círculo verde não acompanha (2 imagem).

[image: 1]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código css:

```
.image_inner_container{
border-radius: 50%;
padding: 5px;
background: #833ab4; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4); 
background: linear-gradient(#fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
}
.green_icon{
background-color: #4cd137;
position: absolute;
right: 465px;
bottom: 170px;
height: 23px;
width: 23px;
border:3px solid white;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Código html:

```
<div class="green_icon"></div>
<div class="image_inner_container">
<a href="<?php echo site_url($account_type . '/manage_profile');?>">
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/uploads/'.$this->session- 
>userdata('login_type').'_image/'.$this->session- 
>userdata('login_user_id').'.jpg');?>" class="img-circle" width="125" 
height="125">
</div>
```

Comment: Iae, cara! Facilite pra gente aí. Poste a parte do HTML relacionada ao problema. ;)

Comment: Coloque `position: relative;` em `.image_inner_container`.

Comment: Sam, em parte resolveu, acompanha a imagem, porém não fica não posição indicada acima.

Comment: Coloque a div do círculo verde dentro da div da foto.

Comment: o círculo verde mudou de lado, mas a posição não!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque a div do círculo verde dentro da div do avatar e coloque `position: relative;` na `div.image_inner_container`  e ajuste os valores `right` e `bottom` do círculo verde para posicionar onde quer:

```css
.image_inner_container{
position: relative;
border-radius: 50%;
padding: 5px;
background: #833ab4; 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4); 
background: linear-gradient(#fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 1;
}
.green_icon{
background-color: #4cd137;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 23px;
width: 23px;
border:3px solid white;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_inner_container">
   <div class="green_icon"></div>
   <a href="<?php echo site_url($account_type . '/manage_profile');?>">
   <img src="<?php echo base_url('/uploads/'.$this->session- 
   >userdata('login_type').'_image/'.$this->session- 
   >userdata('login_user_id').'.jpg');?>" class="img-circle" width="125" 
   height="125">
</div>
```

Você está posicionando errado o círculo verde, está pegando como referência a página toda. Ao usar `position: absolute`, o elemento pega como referência a página toda. Para posicionar um elemento dentro de outro, primeiro é preciso que ele esteja dentro, e a div-pai tenha `position: relative;`. [Este artigo](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) (em inglês) explica bem o funcionamento da propriedade `position`.

Comment: Obrigado, Sam! Funcionou.